# Modifying U-boot booting script and DHCP command script in Petalinux

Tags: linux, dhcp, u-boot, yocto, petalinux

I want to try the following things :

1. Modify the booting arguments of u-boot of my Petalinux project which is currently using the Xilinx Kernel. I want to modify it such that it runs DHCP during booting of the u-boot itself to acquire an IP address for itself and the IP for TFTP server from our central IT infrastructure.

I know this is possible to do with x86_64 processors running a CentOS grub during the boot process, as thats what systems in our office use. The Wiki page for DHCP also says additional options for acquiring IP address for TFTP server can be added in the DHCP packet. I want to simply try this for ARM processors.

This has been mentioned in the following link :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol

2. As you guessed, along with modification of boot arguments to add DHCP in the boot process, I want to modify the DHCP command script to add the TFTP option (if possible for the Petalinux DHCP)

This should essentially look like this ,

1. U-boot starts booting
2. It calls DHCP in the process to obtain its own and TFTP server IP from central DHCP server
3. This DHCP command then along with obtaining its own IP also obtains TFTP server IP

Comment: Of course it's possible. Switching `autoload` on should enable dhcp and tftp support on a full-featured u-boot, I guess. Did you compile your own u-boot? What about your u-boot environment?

Comment: Hi Phillipos, No I am using the one which comes with PetaLinux. Is this autoload option present in menuconfig of U-Boot? I will have a look at it. I have not yet compiled my own U-Boot, but I am in the process of doing so, because we believe there is some issue with the configuration which results from PetaLinux. Your views?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PetaLinux, so my view doesn't really count. But building your own U-Boot is far from being a rocket size and gives you full control over what you have.